# Switching user with gdmflexiserver from i3

Tags: environment-variables, i3, session, gdm3, xdg

[Apparently](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5cedk5/is_there_a_way_to_switch_user_with_i3_how_do_you/d9w03vd/), when using gdm3 (the default of Ubuntu 18.04) we should be able to run `gdmflexiserver` to get a new greeter and log in with resp. switch to another user.

When running the command in my i3 session, I get

```
$ gdmflexiserver 
Could not identify the current session.
```

The problem [seems to be](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gdm-list/2008-May/msg00039.html) that `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE` is not set:

```
$ env | grep "XDG"
XDG_VTNR=2
XDG_SESSION_ID=3
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/i3:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=i3
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=i3
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-i3:/etc/xdg
```

How can I make the gdm3-i3 combo set `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE` during login (or whenever appropriate)?

Comment: This might be of interest to you: [xorg - Equivalent for `dm-tool switch-to-user `otheruser in different display managers - Unix &amp; Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297980/equivalent-for-dm-tool-switch-to-user-otheruser-in-different-display-managers "xorg - Equivalent for `dm-tool switch-to-user `otheruser in different display managers - Unix &amp; Linux Stack Exchange")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround (may be specific to Ubuntu 18.04): Access the login screen by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. It doesn't advertise it, but you can log in as another user without killing the original session. Switching back and forth works just fine.